# Sencha Panel Object

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have two questions folks:

1. How to create Sencha panel object?
2. How to hide and show panel?

Answer (score 1):

creating a panel in Sencha Touch 2 is very easy:

```
var myPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    html: 'my panel'
});
```

or if you just want to define your class that extends Ext.Panel:

```
Ext.define('myPanel',{
    extend: 'Ext.Panel'
});
```

to show and hide your panel, set a reference to it and use `show()` or `hide()` methods respectively

Comment: ,how to set the refrence of panel in controller file ,can u suggest something